# Bing Maps Location object - how is equality determined?

Tags: c#, bing-maps

In some code I'm running, I have two different instances of the Location object from the Bing Maps api:

```
Location l1 = new Location(50, 50);
Location l2 = new Location(50, 50);
```

However when I run `Console.WriteLine(l1.Equals(l2))` I get `false`. Why is that? And how would I override the Equals and GetHashCode methods such that the above evaluates to true?

<s>I'd also just like to note that for some reason finding documentation for Location has been impossible for me.</s>(Nevermind, found it: [HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846500.aspx) but it's still not helpful) I've also tried looking directly at the definition of the Location object to find its Equals and GetHashCode methods to no avail.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's worth pointing out that the documentation does not define an Equals method. Which means that the Equals method you are seeing is defined by .NET and compares the object addresses as noted by Graffito.

When it comes to comparing coordinates you should only look at the first 5 or 6 decimal places. 6 decimal places has an accuracy of 10cm which in most cases is close enough to be the same. If you direct comparison of all decimal places you may find that coordinates that are meant to be the same are not due to floating point error that might occur somewhere down the line. Here is a good way to check if two Location objects are the same:

```
public bool AreEqual(Location l1, Location l2){
    return Math.Round(l1.Latitude, 6) == Math.Round(l2.Latitude, 6) &&
        Math.Round(l1.Longitude, 6) == Math.Round(l2.Longitude, 6);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get false because object addresses are compared, not content. 
So run:

```
Console.WriteLine(l1.Longitude==l2.Longitude && l1.Latitude==l2.Latitude) ;
```

Comment: "Bing.Maps.Location does not contain a definition for areEqual." I've tried using the .Equals method instead for l1 and l2 but I'm still getting false.

Comment: I understand how to get the two values to equal each other. My question is how come the standard .Equals method returns false? On what basis is the equality evaluated?

Comment: JavaScript actually has two different approaches for testing equality. Primitives like strings and numbers are compared by their value, while objects like arrays, dates, and **plain objects are compared by their reference**. That comparison by reference basically checks to see if the objects given refer to the same location in memory.

Comment: @Graffito How does this relate to javascript..?

Comment: It is exactly the same for .net languages and javaScript. I wrote "JavaScript" by error because the Bing or Googlemap APIs are often used in Javascript.